# Dynamic values in linq query by other field and boolean value

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

```
var results = 
    (from p in DBContext.Sources
    orderby p.AccountTypeId
    group p by new { p.AccountTypeId } into g
    select new ObjectItem
    {
        AccountTypeId = g.Key.AccountTypeId,
        Packages = 
            (from pkg in g
            group pkg by new
            {
                pkg.PackageId,
                pkg.Enabled
            } into pg
            select new ATSourcePackageItem
            {
                PackageId = pg.Key.PackageId,
                DisplayName = pg.Key.DisplayName,
                CategoryId = pg.Key.DisplayCategoryId,
                Prices = 
                    (from pr in pg
                    group pr by new { pr.Fpt, pr.Price } into prg
                    select new ATSourcePriceItem
                    {
                        FPT = prg.Key.Fpt,
                        Amount = prg.Key.Price
                    })
            })
    }).ToList();
```

I want to subtract `Amount` by 10 when `CategoryId` equals 7 and when a condition is true.

Is it possible to somehow do this within this linq query because the Amount object doesn't have a setter and this is the only place how I can edit the value.

For example if I do something like:

`Amount = prg.Key.Price - 10`

I'm able to get the value I want, but I want also to set that for specific category and if the boolean value is true.

Comment: "Amount object doesn't have a setter" then how are you setting it in this query?  Is it a constructor parameter instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a ternary operator here :

```
//Amount = prg.Key.Price
Amount = (pg.Key.DisplayCategoryId == 7 && your_boolean_here) ? 
    prg.Key.Price - 10 : prg.Key.Price
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can do this:

```
Amount = prg.Key.Price - 10
```

You can also do this:

```
Amount = {bool expression} ? prg.Key.Price - 10 : prg.Key.Price
```

or just

```
Amount = prg.Key.Price - ({bool expression} ? 10 : 0)
```

Comment: Thanks D, but the other answer was the one I need, it included both the condition and the categoryid. Have a good day

Comment: @Laziale No worries - glad you got what you needed.